# How can I compile(generate a .sln file or something similar) a project via meson

Tags: c++, llvm, project, projects-and-solutions, meson-build

I have the following problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2no8.png)

```
G:\Programs\Soft\Coding\C\VisualStudio\Coders\rellume>meson build
The Meson build system
Version: 1.0.0
Source dir: G:\Programs\Soft\Coding\C\VisualStudio\Coders\rellume
Build dir: G:\Programs\Soft\Coding\C\VisualStudio\Coders\rellume\build
Build type: native build
Project name: rellume
Project version: undefined
C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.31.31107 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31107 for x64")
C linker for the host machine: link link 14.31.31107.0
C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.31.31107 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31107 for x64")
C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.31.31107.0
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
meson.build:14: WARNING: Project targets '>=0.49' but uses feature introduced in '0.52.0': include_type arg in dependency.
llvm-config found: NO need ['>=12', '<16']
Run-time dependency LLVM found: NO (tried config-tool)
meson.build:19: WARNING: Project targets '>=0.49' but uses feature introduced in '0.52.0': include_type arg in dependency.
llvm-config found: NO need ['>=12', '<16']
Run-time dependency LLVM found: NO (tried config-tool)

meson.build:17:2: ERROR: Dependency "llvm" not found, tried config-tool

A full log can be found at G:\Programs\Soft\Coding\C\VisualStudio\Coders\rellume\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
WARNING: Running the setup command as `meson [options]` instead of `meson setup [options]` is ambiguous and deprecated.
```

I understand that meson does not see LLVM-Config, how can I prescribe a path to it through meson?
I'm trying to compile this: https://github.com/aengelke/rellume

I apologize for the stupid questions, but I used to deal only with cmake and in cmake you can register -DLLVM_DIR="" - everything, specifying the path to LLVM itself, everything will work for me, but how can I specify the same path in meson or how can I compile the project above in meson?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) Please copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: I'll do it now.

Comment: Your title ask one question ("How to generate a Visual Studio solution?") while the body of your question ask something completely different ("How to use `llvm-config` from Meson?"). Please make sure that the title is a short summary of the actual question or the problem you have.

Comment: @Some programmer dude meson gives an error. It is necessary that there is no error
and after that everything will be generated through ninja

Comment: @OSPFv3 did you install or build LLVM on your own?

Comment: @ElvisOric yes. I solved the problem by installing meson + llvm in msys2 and llvm was automatically picked up from msys2

Comment: @OSPFv3 Maybe you can answer your own question, it might be helpful for others.